# KDE Redirect application links to wrong address

Tags: kde, redirect, calibre

I am using ubuntu 16.04 with kde 5.

I am trying to authorize calibre to access my goodreads account. When I click on the link the browser opens the login page instead of opening the authorization page. When I click on the notification I can look at the real address for a fraction of a second then the address redirects to the login address.

Can I change this behavior or at least access a log to see opened links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround. I changed the default browser to be Firefox instead of the default KDE handler.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the site intercepting your deep link request, probably because its login cookie isn't present.  If Goodreads doesn't offer a "stay logged in" option, what you're attempting may never work (because the cookie isn't persistent, so can only be kept for as long as the browser remains open following a login).  If it does, you should be able to log in with the "stay logged in" option marked, and then this deep link will work until the cookie expires (many "forever" login cookies actually expire after something like thirty days).

Comment: This seems to be the cause of the problem. I was able to find a solution which is to set /usr/bin/firefox as default web browser. But I believe that KDE should have just passed the link directly to firefox without handling the redirect.

Comment: If Firefox isn't the default browser, KDE/Kubuntu will open the default browser (whatever that might be) when you open a URL link from the desktop.  That browser won't have your Firefox login cookie.  Setting the file associations for the file type can override this, if there's a reason to want something other than Firefox as your default browser, but Firefox to open this link.

Comment: The behaviour before changing default to firefox was the link is sent to KDE default handler then it would be open in firefox. Why would setting firefox directly (I invalidated cache/cookies inside firefox) opens the token page after login while using the default just redirects to the success page?